# Does a cryogenic liquid propellant engine exist capable of using multiple fuels?

Tags: fuel, engine-design, cryogenics

For example, a rocket engine which can use both liquid methane and liquid hydrogen.

Comment: It would be quite possible to build such an engine. But you would need to over-build all aspects of it to an extreme level, and use mechanisms, especially pumps and injectors, that function over a *much* wider range of conditions than normal. The end result will be *many* times the mass, and produce less efficient thrust, than a dedicated engine. Or even a cluster of dedicated engines strapped together, each optimized for its specific fuel!

Comment: @PcMan something close being the RD-701, which was intended to operate from mostly kerosene within the atmosphere and mostly hydrogen later in flight. It was practically two engines mashed together, with separate preburners/turbopumps for LOX/kerosene and LOX/LH2. Even then, the LOX/LH2 preburner ran from kerosene early in flight and required a small amount of kerosene to continue operating with LH2 fuel after the switch.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff that was a cool engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RL10 has been experimentally fired on methane and propane as well as hydrogen. This did entail modifications to several components of the engine; for the methane version:

> Fuel component modifications were unique and were accomplished under the contract; assemblies that were changed were the pump, turbine, thrust control, injector, and thrust chamber.

So it’s not exactly the same engine.

https://yarchive.net/space/rocket/rl10.html
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RL10

Comment: If pump, turbine, thrust control, injector, and thrust chamber were modified, only the nozzle was not modified?